# Unable to return struct from C++ back to C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a C# program that is calling into a native C++ dll.

The C# has a the following struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Phenomenon
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] public char Type;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] public double Jd;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] public double Loc_jd;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)] public double Angle;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)] public char Tran_dir;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)] public Int16 Warning;
}
```

The C++ program has the following struct definition:

```
   typedef struct
   {
      char type;
      double jd;
      double loc_jd;
      double angle;
      char tran_dir;
      short int warning;
   } phenomenon;
```

The C# program instantiates the Phenomenom objects has the following call to the C++ method:

```
Phenomenon[] phenomena = new Phenomenon[6];
short status = rsttwi_temp(phenomena);
```

The C++ simply updates the struct and returns. Here is the C++ function:

```
__declspec(dllexport) short int rsttwi_temp (phenomenon phen[1])
{
    phen[0].type = 'Z';
    phen[0].jd = 1.1;
    phen[0].loc_jd = 2.2;
    phen[0].angle = 3.3;
    phen[0].tran_dir = 4.4;
    phen[0].warning = '0';

    return 0;
}
```

From the C# program when I print out the values of the struct after the call to the C++ function, the struct has not been updated (i.e. it is the same as before the C++ function was called). It seems that the C++ program is able to see the values and update them, but upon return the C# never sees the updates to the values in the struct. Thinking it was a value vs. reference problem, I even tried to do this with a class in the C# program, instead of the struct. Still no luck.

Question:
What marshaling do I need to allow the called C++ function to be able to update the actual struct that was passed to it?

Thank you.
-Greg Edwards
Total Immersion Software

Answer (score 2):

It's not easy to understand why this doesn't work without seeing the definition of your C# function.  I'm guessing it looks something like this though

```
[DllImport("somedll.dll")]
public static extern Int16 rsttwi_temp(Phenomenon[] array);
```

I don't have much experience working pinvoking a fixed size native array.  But what you could do is change the C++ signature to take a pointer instead of a fixed size array and switch the managed code to pass by reference.  For example

```
[DllImport("somedll.dll")]
public static extern Int16 rsttwi_temp(ref Phenomenon value);

__declspec(dllexport) short int rsttwi_temp (phenomenon* phen)
```

Comment: Jared,

I have been able to use the ref, but since the C++ code would have to be modified heavily to use it, I was trying to avoid using it.

Thank you for your suggestion. I may ultimately have to do it this way.

-Greg

Comment: @Greg, another option is to create a second method which has the signature I specified and use it to call the first.  That way you avoid changing the existing code but still get the benefit of working PInvoke

Answer (score 1):

Using in this way works:

C++

```
 __declspec(dllexport) short int rsttwi_temp (phenomenon* phen)
{
    phen->jd = 1.1;
    phen->loc_jd = 2.2;
    phen->angle = 3.3;
    phen->warning = 0;
    return 0;
}

typedef struct
       {
          double jd;
          double loc_jd;
          double angle;
          short int warning;
       } phenomenon;
```

C#

```
[DllImport("somedll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Int16 rsttwi_temp(ref Phenomenon value);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Phenomenon
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
            public double Jd;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
            public double Loc_jd;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
            public double Angle;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
            public Int16 Warning;
        }
```

C# Call

```
 Phenomenon phenomena = new Phenomenon();
 short status = rsttwi_temp(ref phenomena);
```

Comment: That's what Jared already suggested, except you've removed members of the struct that might have been important.  What's your contribution exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I put this example because, I found this question and I needed something similar to implement, but when i finish read all the thread and I tried to tested didn´t work. So I modified. My intention was made the change to the code, so the person that need implement and struct doesn´t need to lost an hour to understand. If you want i can delele this.

Answer (score -2):

C# char != C++ char.

C# char == C++ wchar_t

C++ char == C# byte